# Disable escaping characters in redirect_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I have a redirect_to used in my controller that proceeds to the `[@product, @version]`. I get redirected to the `/same%2Fpath%2Fwith%2Fannoying%symbols` instead of expected path.

How can I solve this issue and replace unnecessary `%2F` with expected `/`?

**UPDATED**

```
# config/routes.rb
constraints(number: /[.\d]+/, name: /[A-Za-z0-9_.-\/]+/) do
  resources :products, except: [:index], param: :name do
    resources :versions, except: [:index], param: :number
  end
end
```

Comment: Please, show corresponding rule from your routes.rb file and your code, using redirect_to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me

```
redirect_to new_product_version_path(@product).gsub('%2F', '/')
```

Of course, you can create this method in `ApplicatonController`

```
  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status_and_flash = {})
    options.gsub!('%2F', '/') if options.respond_to?(:gsub)

    super(options, response_status_and_flash)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CGI::unescape` that was built in Ruby. Like this:

```
redirect_to CGI::unescape(your_string_path)
```

Comment: this is little weird approach. I need to modify absolutely every redirect_to + see updated

Comment: What will be if I'll set not a string, but just `[@product, @version]`?

Comment: You definitely should find a way to built path from your objects, something like this: new_product_verstion_path(@product, @version)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing required parameters to an url helper, something like that:

```
redirect_to new_product_versions_path([@product, @version], name: 'some name', number: 235)
```

I may have mistaken with correct spelling of your url helper name, you can always find correct one by looking into the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: Alexey, I solved my trouble, but thanks for the hint - I've found it helpful